# Incomplete answers

Tags: discussion

I was just posting an answer to a question and realized that I didn't actually have a full solution to the problem. I'll often start typing/formatting my answer as I work on it, and occasionally, I'll get very close to the solution and something doesn't quite work. The answer still provides insight to a solution method, and is at least a starting point for the asker. My intention in actually posting this as an answer is that feedback from others usually "completes" the solution.

Since what I've posted doesn't *technically* answer the question when it is first posted, I assume this isn't allowed. Do others see this as my essentially using a "placeholder" to later complete the solution?

I know that [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244/is-posting-an-incomplete-answer-then-immediately-improving-it-helpful-or-aggrava?rq=1) discussion exists, but I think this is slightly different. I'm not immediately intending to finish up the question. Rather, I'm hoping to open a dialogue that will result in an answer that is educational to both the OP, and myself.

The question/answer that sparked my worry about this: [WeatherData for the 15th day of each month](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/weatherdata-for-the-15th-day-of-each-month/27863)

Comment: Re: _"I'm hoping to open a dialogue"_. The SE sites differ from forums mainly in that dialogues are discouraged here. You may use the chat, and eventually the comments for that kind of interaction. BTW I don't see any problem in _incomplete_ answers as long as they are constructive and help to solve the issue

Comment: I think the constructiveness aspect is probably the most important. I'll gladly upvote an answer that doesn't completely solve the problem, but still offers some nontrivial insights, and I gather that is somewhat consistent with the spirit of SE sites. What won't be acceptable are trivial restatements of the question or discussions of unrelated problems--very few answers are posted like this and most come from new, unregistered users. Rules here are not especially strict, so if you apply usual academic etiquette, I doubt if anyone will look twice even at a technical policy violation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I often see answers prefixed with statements such as "This is a partial answer" or "This is not a complete answer", etc. I have posted such answers myself. I haven't seen any comments complaining about such answers, so I conclude they are permitted.

I think it best that anyone giving a partial answer note that it is partial and explain why it is still worth posting.

Comment: Yes, in many ways, a partial answer is superior to no answer. Even an incomplete answer can provide insights.