# Should I improve my answer based on another?

Tags: discussion

It has happened that another community member posted a partial answer to a question which I had answered. Now mine is imperfect and his is incomplete. Should I edit mine to have one complete answer? If he did not want to provide a full solution, should he have made a comment instead of posting the answer, such that I could have improved mine?

Weakly related [Incomplete answers](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1039/2036)

edit: I clarified the last sentence.

edit2: Generalised the question. I never intended to attack anyone but thought the example did not hurt.

Comment: If incomplete answer is useful the author deserves a credit for it. If you feel you can provide extended version, useful for futore visitors, I'd say, go for it. It is always better to have something done from the *a* to *z*. Just point the source of the idea in your edit. (*it's all just my personal view*)

Comment: It is not a bad idea to talk to the other person before or at the same time as posting on meta. ;-) *I* don't mind at all if you incorporate my suggestion into your answer, but others (especially people who care a lot about reputation) might be sensitive about getting what they feel is proper credit.  The key is to talk to the other person *first*, that way there won't be misunderstandings or bad feelings.